# Flutter and Firebase Analytics - events are not logged (but sometimes works)

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-analytics

I have a simple application, to which I just added Firebase.

Since 4 days I am trying to make it work, and yesterday finally I started seeing events coming in DebugView (which proves that I configured it correctly). It was moment of pure joy, as each single event was recorded in DebugView (no matter how many times I clicked a button -> all events reached Firebase).

This happiness didn't last long however.

Today it stopped work, but not like "never works", but it skips like 95-99% of events (some events sometimes gets to DebugView. Wow! Pure magic.

Using `logcat`, I can see all events are successfully uploaded/sent.

I wonder if there is any undocumented "magical" thing that might me blocking my events?
Or is Firebase down today (21st Sept 2022)?

##### Please note that:

When my events passes - it shows "1" in **USERS IN LAST 30 MINUTES** which is correct.

[image]

When events are not reaching DebugView, then nothing is shown in **USERS IN LAST 30 MINUTES** (which basically means that it is not only problem with DebugView - but actually no activity is reaching Firebase AT ALL).

Following picture proves that some events reached Firebase (but dozens other events, like `screen_view` or my custom `dummy_event` never got there).

[image]

Last picture proves that my events actually are successfully sent.
[image]

#### EDIT 25th Sept 2022

I deleted Firebase project and created a new one, run `flutterfire configure` and guess what? It started to work WITHOUT any other change in the code. (please note that I was running `flutterfire configure` many time for previous firebase project as well, without any result).

I am frustrated that I wasted few hours on looking for a bug in my code, while it was some "magic" on Firebase side that simply made it NOT WORKING.

##### So do you think it is over now? And that everything works?

You can't be farther from truth.

[image]

This image shows that there was 1 active user. Yes, it was me debugging app using DEBUG build. So since it was working, and decided to make final release build to my device (`flutter run --release`) and guess what?

Yeap - nothing shows in Firebase again. Simply my release build, installed on my device does not shows any activity on Firebase.

- Is it because it was not downloaded from Google Play?
- Is it because I have some misconfiguration?
- Is it because Firebase has bug?

Who knows... Firebase is like Hogwart - full of magic.

Comment: Hey did your 'dummy_event' ever get logged in analytics' debugview?

Comment: Yes, it did few times, then stopped. Then after 24hrs showed in normal analytics (almost 100 times which is expected as I triggered it many times).